# How to get the result from firebase first and then redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

i have a function in my app to get some data from firebase and after completion of that firebase on function, i need to redirect it to another page.
But in my code when i press the button it will quickly redirect to another bage so the function is not processed. How can i do this?

```
 $('#pg-myb-inde #testBtn').on('click',function(){

         myFirebaseRef.orderByChild('emailid').equalTo('mishan@gmail.com').on('value',function(userSnap){
            var user=userSnap.val();
//            $('#UserPage .person-name').empty();
//            $('#UserPage .person-name').append('' +
//                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i> '+user.fname);
            console.log('appended');
            console.log(user.fname);


        });

        location.href = "/another-web-page";
    })
```

Comment: And why don't you just put your redirecting code in the `on('value'...)` callback?

Comment: actually what i want is if the on function has more than one iterations i cannot put this  code within 'on' function. @ A. Wolff

Comment: Do you want to wait for a specific value in the `on('value'` handler? Something like `if (user.name != 'Nazil')`?

Comment: yeah, i need a value from that 'on' function

Comment: can you please help me in this problem @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('#pg-myb-inde #testBtn').on('click',function(){
    var query = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild('emailid').equalTo('mishan@gmail.com');
    query.on('value',function(userSnap){
        var user=userSnap.val();
        location.href = "/another-web-page";
    });
})
```

The only thing I've changed is move the setting of the location *into* the callback function.

If that is indeed what you're looking for, it may help if you put some logging statements into this code:

```
$('#pg-myb-inde #testBtn').on('click',function(){
    var query = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild('emailid').equalTo('mishan@gmail.com');
    console.log('Before Firebase query');
    query.on('value',function(userSnap){
        console.log('In Firebase callback');
        var user=userSnap.val();
        location.href = "/another-web-page";
    });
    console.log('After Firebase query');
})
```

Now when you run this code, the output is most likely *not* what you expected:

```
Before Firebase query
After Firebase query
In Firebase callback
```

The reason for this is that the data is asynchronously retrieved from Firebase. When you call `on()` it starts the request to the server. But since it may take a while before the response comes back from the server, your browser doesn't wait for the answer and just continues with the code *after* the query. When when the data come back from the server, your callback is invoked.

Comment: Then What is the solution for this? If i need to get some result from first firebase query and then i need to make a second query based on the first query result?     @Frank

Comment: You'll need to nest the second query inside the callback of the first one. `query.on('value', function(snapshot) { ref.child(snapshot.key()).on('value', ...`

Comment: Yes i did like that . Thank you very much!